# Syncing virtual machines - dynamically allocated or fixed allocation VHD?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, sync, vhd

When you run a virtual machine that you want to periodically sync, is it generally faster to use a dynamically allocated VHD or a fixed allocation VHD?

I'm sure this depends on a lot of factors, including:

- How much data changes between syncs
- What sort of data data changes between syncs
- What utility you're using to sync
- The storage mediums used for the sync

But is there a hard-and-fast rule?

In my case I'm carrying around a Virtualbox Ubuntu guest on a USB SSD, and want to `rsync` to a SATA HDD once per week.

Answer (score 0):

In general disk i/o from inside the VM should be better with fixed drive (as opposed to dynamically allocated) because of the overhead when the host OS expands the file that represents the vdisk. 
 But if you rsync files from inside the OS (inside Ubuntu in your case), as these are already existing, the type of the underlying VM disk should not matter for the sync speed. 
If you wanted to rsync the VM disk as a whole, I think you better consider working with snapshots and/or some mix of VBoxManage clonehd/clonevm/export(to ova) approaches.